# Facing a casting error for splitter in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to camel and I have written a code for splitter. 
I've written a context.xml which contains the routes and the beans for mapping the POJOs, and a FileSplitter.java file which contains the following code:

```
public class FileSplitter {
    public List<Object> split(Exchange exchange) throws IOException {
        List<Object> outputList;
        outputList = (List<Object>) exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
        return outputList;
    } 
}
```

I'm getting an error which goes like this.
This is the console output:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to java.util.List
        at mainJava.FileSplitter.split(FileSplitter.java:15)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The error appears to be on this line:

```
outputList = (List<Object>) exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
```

Comment: Please add camel routes code.

Comment: What do you think `getBody(File.class)` should return? Why?

Comment: <camel:route id="route2">
  <camel:from uri="direct:splitter" />
  <camel:split parallelProcessing="false" streaming="false">
  <camel:method ref="splitter" method="split" />
  <camel:to uri="direct:output" />
  </camel:split>
 </camel:route>

Answer (score 2):

The call `getBody(File.class)` will return a `java.io.File` instance, you cannot cast that to a `List` then, its always a `java.io.File` type.

Its like write in Java

```
File file = new File("foo.txt");
List list = (List) file;
```

Which you cannot do, and you get a type cast exception also.